# Excel VBA search range depending on time of day

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of cells in the format of "dd/mm/yy  HH:MM:SS" and I am wanting to count the number of cells that have a date and time within the following range depending on the time of day.

If Current Time is < 07:00 Then

```
Count Occurances in range between 07:00 the previous day and now
```

Else

```
Count occurances between 07:00 today and now
```

End If

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will most likely work for you. Its also pretty straightforward and easily changed to reference the proper sheets and cells that you need it to look at. I hope this helped!

```
Sub CountingNumberOfOccurancesWithingRangeDependingOnTime()
    Dim curTime As Date
    Dim preTime As Date
    Dim todayTime As Date
    Dim curHour As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer

    curTime = Now
    curHour = Format(curTime, "HH")
    preTime = curTime - 1

    x = 1

    If curHour < 7 Then
        Do Until Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value = Empty
            cellTime = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value

            If cellTime > preTime And cellTime < curTime Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    Else
        todayTime = Date & " " & "07:00:00"
        Do Until Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value = Empty
            cellTime = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1).Value

            If cellTime > todayTime And cellTime < curTime Then
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop
    End If

    MsgBox counter 'This isn't necissary, but it just is here to show the number of cells counted



End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic! I was able to tweak this to fit my project completely. Much appreciated!